# Unit Testing Coroutine Channel return

Tags: android, unit-testing, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

I'm doing a polling every few seconds and returns a Channel with a Result. My problem is how to test it.

Here is my viewmodel code:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
fun fetchInfo() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        channel = fetchInfoUseCase("1")
        channel.consumeEach {
            viewAction.postValue(ViewAction.UPDATE)
        }
    }
}
```

My unit test code:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class MyViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    val instantTask = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    val coroutinesTestRule = CoroutinesTestRule()

    private val fetchInfo = mockk<FetchInfoUseCase>()

    private val channel = Channel<Result<MyModel, MyError>>()

    private val viewModel = MyViewModel(fetchInfo)

    @Test
    fun dispatchFunction_viewActionUpdate() {
        prepareScenario()
        viewModel.fetchInfo()
        coVerify(exactly = 1) { fetchInfo(any()) }

        assertEquals(
            viewModel.viewAction.value,
            ViewAction.UPDATE
        )
    }

    private fun prepareScenario() {
        coEvery { fetchInfo(any()) } returns channel
    }
}
```

My in my test, *viewModel.viewAction.value* is always null. 
How can I validate that the viewAction is being called and the value is *ViewAction.UPDATE*?